# Simple E-Mail sending working only from Thonny

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp

I started a little Raspberry project and stuck with sending a simple E-Mail. Gmail smtp is set up. The code works fine from Thonny (although it sends the E-Mal only for the first receiver and not both), but when I trigger it from the terminal (python report.py), I get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "report.py", line 15, in <module>
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

As I mentioned above, from Thonny it is working. I plan to trigger some script like this time scheduled through Crontab. I set up the Crontab file, but it does nothing, I assume because it makes an error every time.

Thank you for help in advance!

The report.py content:

```
import smtplib, ssl

port = 465  # For SSL
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
sender_email = "****@gmail.com"
receiver_email = "****@gmail.com,xxxx@gmail.com"
password = "****"
message = """\
Subject: Hi there

This message is sent from Python."""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

Comment: I just noticed, the sender gets an E-Male every time the Cron-Job is running with the same error message as above, plus: DNS Error: 7780855 DNS type 'mx' lookup of raspberrypi responded with code NXDOMAIN Domain name not found: raspberrypi

Comment: In the terminal, try calling the script like this: `python3 report.py` - your system's default python might be python2.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `context` argument to [smtplib.SMTP_SSL](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL) was added in Python 3.3.

[Thonny](https://thonny.org/) uses a built-in Python3.7 interpreter, but many Unix-like operating systems' default Python interpreter is Python 2.x.  Explicitly call the script with Python 3 to prevent the error:

```
python3 report.py
```